# Combo box VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am using around 8-10 comboboxes(form control),each one having the same list of items populated. Based on the user's selection from the dropdown, a certain value is displayed in a different cell. I wanted to know if there is way to do this without using a loop(for dropdowns) as all have the same function. Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim ws As Sheets
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("S1 Fuel Consumption", "EF_Stat", "Summary"))
Dim i As Integer


For i = 1 To 8
With ws(1).Shapes("Fuel " & i).ControlFormat    ~~> 'This is the loop I'm talking about(for 8 shapes)

Select Case .ListIndex

Case 1
ws(3).Range("B" & i).Value = Empty
Case 2
ws(3).Range("B" & i).Value = ws(2).Range("B4").Value
Case 3
ws(3).Range("B" & i).Value = ws(2).Range("C4").Value
Case 4
ws(3).Range("B" & i).Value = ws(2).Range("D4").Value

End Select
End With
Next i
```

Comment: I'm not sure from your question what exactly you are asking? Are you trying to fill the comboboxes without a loop? You're code doesn't have a loop in it.

Comment: I have 8-10 already populated comboboxes. In the code, you'll see a loop " for i = 1 to 8.....shapes("fuel " & i)"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the same macro to all of the comboboxes and use:

```
With WS(1).Dropdowns(Application.Caller)
```

to get a reference to the combobox that triggered the macro.

If you need to figure out the 'i' value you were using in the loop originally, you can do something like this:

```
Dim ws As Sheets
Dim sCaller As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rgOutput As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("S1 Fuel Consumption", "EF_Stat", "Summary"))

sCaller = Application.Caller

Set rgOutput = ws(3).Range("B" & Replace(sCaller, "Fuel ", ""))

Select Case ws(1).DropDowns(sCaller).ListIndex

    Case 1
        rgOutput.Value = vbNullString
    Case 2
        rgOutput.Value = ws(2).Range("B4").Value
    Case 3
        rgOutput.Value = ws(2).Range("C4").Value
    Case 4
        rgOutput.Value = ws(2).Range("D4").Value

End Select
```

Comment: Will this reference also be able to store separate values for the choices among the different comboboxes? I am sorry if it wasn't clear before. As you can see in the code that for say "fuel 1"(dropdown) depending on the item chosen from dropdown, a value is displayes { Range("B4").value}

Comment: How is the range determined?

Comment: Each value should be stored in a different cell. Like suppose there are 4 comboboxes, having options "this" "that" & "there". Now say, for the 1st combobox, if the option is "this", a value "0.1" will be stored in a cell say B1. For 2nd combobox, if option is "that", 0.2 will be stored in say B2

Comment: I tried using your code for a different purpose => to populate my dropdowns. But it says "unable to get dropdowns property of worksheet class" :/

Comment: Still not really clear how the code should determine what goes where. If you need to obtain the relevant `i` value you had originally, you could use `CLng(replace(application.Caller, "Fuel ", ""))`

Comment: Ahh my bad. If I choose diesel from "Fuel 1", B1 should display 0.1. Similarly, If I choose diesel from "Fuel 2", B2 should display 0.1.

Comment: Then you can use my last suggestion to get the 1 or 2 part from the name of whichever combobox was clicked.

Comment: I am sorry for bugging again and again. I am very new to VBA so I still don't know a lot of functions. Can you please show me how to do the same by editing the answer you originally had posted? Thanks

Comment: It says type mismatch while highlighting the "scaller = application.caller" code line

Comment: How are you running the code? Assigning the macro to a Forms (not ActiveX) control and then using that?

Comment: Ohh there was some error in the naming, got it! Thanks! But as you see, in this code the particular value(in the B cell) will be displayed only according to the name of the combobox(in this case Fuel 1,2 or 3). Can I display it for some arbitrary cells?

Comment: I don't know what you mean - can you clarify?

Comment: In the above code line.. rgoutput = ...Range("B" &..."Fuel ", "") This gives output in the cell B depending upon for example whether it is "Fuel 1" or "Fuel 2"  rgouput will be displayed in B2 and B3 respectively. Can I display rgoutput results in arbitrary cells like maybe B4?

Comment: Of course as long as there is some way for the code to determine where the cells are.